# Airtight seal in blender animation

Tags: animation, physics, cloth-simulation

I want to model a rigid bowl with a diaphragm over the top of the bowl.

I want an airtight seal between the two.

I want to be able to animate changing the pressure inside so that the diaphragm rises and falls with the pressure change.

The two things I'm having trouble with are:

1. An airtight seal between the bowl and the diaphragm.
2. Animating pressure changes.

Here's an example of how far I've gotten.

If you run the animation the diaphragm will drop onto the bowl and deform nicely.

I just want to know how to go about attaching the cloth to the bowl with an airtight seal so I can pressurise the inside.

[bowl_and_diaphragm.blend](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ajsakt1fcnt0m0l/bowl_and_diaphragm.blend?dl=0)

Any tips on where to look?

Many thanks.

Comment: Sorry Graham but you want to many things at once! Better split it in multiple questions that can be then applied to different problems. Also, may be provide info on what you've tried so far, screenshots etc., that will help you get better answers.

Comment: Looks like the new cloth physics pressure setting might have what you need

Comment: @Bruno, thanks for that. I hope the edits clarifies things.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos, thanks, yes, I'd got that far.